# How to turn any moving object?

Tags: java

I am simply making an aquarium. Right now, I have only one fish inside it. It is moving forward and when it hits the frame it again moves back. But the face of the fish is still facing towards right side. When it moves back, I want it's face to change. How can I do that? Here is my code.

```
package aquarium;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Aquarium extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
Random r = new Random();
Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
int x = 0, y= 30;
int velX = 1 ,velY =1;
private ImageIcon fish2image;
private ImageIcon fish1image;
ImageIcon image  = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../res/aquarium.gif"));
ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../res/smallFish.gif"));
int numberFish = 12;
Aquarium(){

}
 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    image.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
    image1.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
    t.start();
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   if(x<0 || x>465){
    velX = -velX; 
    }
x += velX;

repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Aquarium a = new Aquarium();

     JFrame f = new JFrame();

    f.setTitle("The Aquarium");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setBounds(500,200,500,300); //left,top,width,height 
    f.add(a);

}
}
```

Comment: Answers to this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1708011/10077